# how to set default ruby with rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It is defaulting to 1.8.7 which comes with Mac OS x.  I am trying to use RVM and use 1.9.3
I tried rvm use default and is says -bash: rvm: command not found

my bashrc file has

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin
```

Comment: Have you closed the terminal window and reopened a new one after installing RVM, or otherwise done something to refresh your shell?

Comment: yes.  I restarted the terminal.

Comment: Next question would be is RVM installed to that location?

Comment: yes it is.  I can go to the /users/Victoria/.rvm

Comment: I believe thats thats the same path right?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Typing `rvm list` will give you a list of the installed rubies you have, like this:

```
    ree-1.8.7-2010.02 [ i686 ]
    ruby-1.8.7-p249 [ i686 ]
    ruby-1.9.2-p180 [ x86_64 ]
    ruby-1.9.2-p180-patched [ x86_64 ]
    ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ]
    ruby-1.9.2-p290-webkit [ x86_64 ]
=*  ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]
```

If the one you want is `ruby-1.9.3-p194`, then type:

```
rvm --default use  ruby-1.9.3-p194
```

First, be careful to follow the installation instructions closely and make sure it's working.

You should also see this line in your bashrc as well:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Then try opening a new shell or try typing:

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

But in general if you're having issues, I'd recommend just re-installing rvm  -- it doesn't take long and it's easy:

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Comment: Try `curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`, and then `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm`

Comment: Will I need to run source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm everytime I open a terminal.  Right now that seems to be the only way it will work.

Comment: It sounds like your `.bashrc` is not getting run when you open a terminal window. Can you confirm that your terminal windows are running `bash` and that the `.bashrc` is getting run?

Comment: Running `ps` in the command window will tell you which shell you're running. If you don't see `bash`, then I'd do some research and post a new question to resolve that. Best of luck!

Comment: Victorias-MacBook-Pro:~ Victoria$ ps
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
 3283 ttys000    0:00.01 -bash

Comment: I resoved the issue further using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106635/rvm-isnt-recognized-until-i-run-source-profile-in-terminal